# Greek and alpha numeric in ggplot2 axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use ggplot2 to make a chart with a axis label of uL, where the 'u' is the greek 'mu'.
to add just mu, I have found this to work

```
p <- ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3), aes(x= x, y=y)) + geom_point()
p + ylab(expression(mu))
```

But I have not been able to place anything else alongside it.
These do not work

```
p + ylab(paste(expression(mu), "foo"))
p + ylab("expression(mu)~foo")
```

Thanks in advance

Sam

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How about this:

```
p <- ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3), aes(x= x, y=y)) + geom_point()
p + ylab(expression(paste(mu,L)))
```

Comment: or even `ylab(expression(mu*L))`